# building cryptomator from source code with eclipse

Tags: java

How can I build cryptomator source code with eclipse ?
When I build with maven in eclipse , the IDE could not solve this function:

```
public static CryptorProvider version1(SecureRandom seeder) {
    return DaggerCryptoLibComponent.builder().secureRandomModule(new SecureRandomModule(seeder)).build().version1();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 20 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `annotations` folders inside `target/generated-sources` of each module to the build path.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Source: https://community.cryptomator.org/t/build-with-eclipse-or-netbeans/345/2